# How to read value from Password Field in Selenium/Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have scenario where in i want to read values from excel and put into username and password field, later want to verify whether username and password got entered in the are proper by comparing with Excel values.

Below is sample code given w.r.t to "gmail".
HTML Code:

```
<input type="password" name="Passwd" id="Passwd">
```

Webdriver Code:

```
Driver.driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");
Driver.driver.findElement(By.name("Passwd")).sendKeys("mahesh");
    System.out.println(Driver.pFLogin.getTxtPassword().getAttribute("value"));
```

Getting error for above code, since password field dont have "value" attribute

Kindly help me on this..

Thanks
Mahesh

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
System.out.println(Driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).getAttribute("value"));
```

make sure, By typing into an input element, you are changing its value attribute as text.

Comment: Even i did the same thing.., For accessing the element i used PageFactory concept(pFLogin.getTxtPassword()).

Also the field is not defined with "value" attribute.., please check the above mentioned HTML code again.

Comment: Just change in html as <input type="text" name="Passwd" id="Passwd">.

Comment: Current all password fields are come with Input Type as "Password" only, and this is secured.

Comment: for testing change it in your application.

Comment: Dynamically i should change or what..?. Please give some more details about your solution
Thanks

Comment: In Your application, change the <input type="text" name="Passwd" id="Passwd"> as. for testing purpose. after completing the testing re-wart back as it is.

Answer (score 0):

try this code once

```
File sr=new File("File path");
    //load file
    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(sr);
    //load workbook
    XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFSheet wsh=wb.getSheetAt(0);
    //read data
    String s1=wsh.getRow(0).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
    String s2=wsh.getRow(0).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
    String s3=wsh.getRow(0).getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
    System.out.println(s1+" "+s2+" "+s3);
    Thread.sleep(3000); 
    fis.close();
    WebDriver d1=new FirefoxDriver();
    d1.get("website url");
    d1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    d1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='username']")).sendKeys(s2);
    d1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys(s3);
    d1.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of the element")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    d1.close();


    FileInputStream fs=new FileInputStream("file path");
    Workbook wb1=WorkbookFactory.create(fs);
    Sheet sh=wb1.getSheetAt(0);
    Row row=sh.createRow(row value);
    //Write data
    Cell cell=row.createCell(cell value);
    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
    cell.setCellValue("ravi");
    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("file path");
    wb1.write(fos);
    fos.close();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If You want to see the password (eg. on screen or while executing test) you can use JSexecutor.

```
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("var arr = document.getElementsByTagName(\"input\");\n" +
            "for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {\n" +
            "    if (arr[i].type == 'password') arr[i].setAttribute('type','text');\n" +
            "}");

    String password = fPassword.getAttribute("value");
    logger.debug("pass:" +password);
```